# .htaccess redirect for .html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, templates, redirect, tinybutstrong

I have a site constructed using the [TinyButStrong](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/) template system, so consisting of pairs of .php pages with .html templates.

What rules should I use in a .htaccess file such that any call to a .html page is redirected to the .php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [NC]
```